# Regex - Find everything between OR-operators except OR between quotes

Tags: regex

I need some help with a Regex. I have a query, that should be splitted between all OR-operators. But if the OR is inside of quotes, it should not splitted.

**Example:**

This is the query:

```
"test1" OR "test2.1 OR test2.2" OR test3 OR test4:"test4.1 OR test4.2"
```

*Expression 1:* I need everything between the OR-operators or start/end of line... (This is not working)

```
(^|OR).*?(OR|$)
```

*Expression 2:* ...except of the ORs between quotes:

```
"(.*?)"
```

The result should be:

```
"test1"
"test2.1 OR test2.2"
test3
test4:"test4.1 OR test4.2"
```

How can I make the first expression work and how can I combine these both expressions?

Thank you for help!

Comment: I guess [`\s*OR\s*(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*$)`](https://regex101.com/r/xC4rJ3/1).

Comment: This is great, but it finds the ORs and not the content between. :D

Comment: So, you are not splitting, you want to match? I doubt it is that easy.

Comment: Which language is this?

Comment: @stribizhev: yes, I want to match. Is it not possible to "reverse" the expression? So I get everything that doesn't match the expression?

Comment: Let's say [it is possible with `\s*((?:(?!OR(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*$)).(?<!OR(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*$)))+)`](https://regex101.com/r/xC4rJ3/2), but is it effecient? No. Even if we add possessive quantifiers: [`\s*((?:(?!OR(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*+$)).(?<!OR(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*+$)))+)`](https://regex101.com/r/xC4rJ3/3). [This string](https://regex101.com/r/xC4rJ3/5) already leads to catastrophic backtracking.

Comment: You can do something like this https://regex101.com/r/xC4rJ3/4 grab the capture or group

Comment: Thank you! Regex is really hard to read..

Comment: @vks: Have a look at when [your regex causes catastrophic backtracking](https://regex101.com/r/xC4rJ3/6). And the string is not that long! I think it is not a good idea to use regex for this task *unless* the strings to process are not exceeding some predefined limit.

Comment: If you were using Lua patterns, an efficient method would've been to use `'%b""'` pattern.

Comment: @stribizhev https://regex101.com/r/xC4rJ3/12 here it does validate a long string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to match everything in quotes or not-OR with:

```
(?:"[^"]+"|\b(?:(?!\bOR\b)[^"])+)+
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xC4rJ3/9)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear what the grammar of your expression is, so I just make a bunch of assumptions and come up with this regex to **match** the tokens between `OR`:

```
\G(\w+(?::"[^"]*")?|"[^"]*")(?:(\s+OR\s+)|\s*$)
```

[**Demo at regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/oK8dP3/2)

I assume that between `OR`, it can be an identifier `\w+`, an identifier with some string `\w+:"[^"]*"`, or a string literal `"[^"]*"`.

<sup>Feel free to substitute your own definition of string literal - I'm using the simplest (and broken) specification `"[^"]*"` as example.</sup>

In every match, the regex starts from where the last match left off (or the beginning of the string) and matches one token (as described above), followed by `OR` or the end of the input string.

The capturing groups at `(\s+OR\s+)` is deliberate - you will need this to check whether the last match actually terminates at the end of the string or not, or whether the input is malformed.

#### Caveat

Do note that while my solution produces the expected result for this case, without a full specification of the grammar of the expression, it's not possible to cater for all possible cases you may want to handle.

Answer (score 2):

```
(?:^|OR(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*+[^"]*$))([\s\S]*?)(?=OR(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*+[^"]*$)|$)
```

You can use this and capture the `groups`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/xC4rJ3/12

Answer (score 1):

This regex works optimally (though it be subject to improvement with a more detailed specification):

```
(?<!\S)(?!OR\s)[^\s"]*(?:"[^"]*"[^\s"]*)*
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gO2zZ8/2)

`(?<!\S)` ensures the match starts at the beginning of the string or after a whitespace character.

`(?!OR\s)` prevents it from matching `OR`

`[^\s"]*(?:"[^"]*"[^\s"]*)*` matches a contiguous series of, in any order:

- sequences of non-whitespace, non-quote characters, or
- a pair of quotes enclosing anything except quotes.

However, I notice that all the tokens in your example consist of:

- a non-quote, non-whitespace sequence (NQ),
- a quoted sequence (Q), or
- an NQ followed immediately by a Q.

If you expect all tokens to match that pattern, you can change the regex to this:

```
(?<!\S)(?!OR\s)(?:[^\s"]*"[^"]*"|[^\s"]+)
```

According to Regex101, it's slightly more efficient (but probably not enough to matter).

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gO2zZ8/3)